# Проблема с выбором элементов из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, объекты

Есть массив объектов такого вида

```
songs: Array(7)
0
:
artist
:
{name: "Redfoo", song: "New Thang"}
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
artist
:
{name: "Hugo", song: "99 Problems"}
__proto__
:
Object
```

Мне нужно сделать так что бы я мог фильтровать по именам(name) и песням(song)(сравнивать названия с тем, что человек введет в `input`).
Но проблема в том что я не знаю как сразу выбрать все имена и песни.

`console.log(songs.artist);` выводит undefined, а `console.log(songs[0].artist);` не подходит так как я получаю только 1 объект.

Как можно получить сразу их все?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `map()`

```js
var songs = [
    { artist : {name: "Redfoo", song: "New Thang"}},
    { artist : {name: "Hugo", song: "99 Problems"}}
];

var pattern = 'Redfoo';

songs.map(function(item) {
    if (item.artist.name == pattern)
      console.log(item.artist);
});
```

Comment: Всё так, как и нужно, спасибо)